# @apply and a style dom-module won't work in Polymer 2.0

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'd like to make my styles `dom-module`, and because I like using the `@apply` css directive, I wish I could do something like :

```
<dom-module id="my-styles">
 <template>
  <style>
   html {
    --big-title: {
     font-size: 1.3em;
     text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    }
   }
  </style>
 </template>>
</dom-module>
```

But if I do that :

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style include="my-styles">
      h1 {
        @apply --big-title;
      }
    </style>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Sadly this won't work. I am not sure why. My question is Can I use the @apply directive in conjunction with the styling `dom-module` solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead assign your properties to `:host`, I would say.

Check this example:
http://jsbin.com/dikacewulu/2/edit?html,output

Here, `:host` refers to the element including the style (so `my-element`). If you really wanted those rules to be available on `html`, you could use `:root`.

Comment: oh yea, that's how it sounds all the code will get `include`d. How could I have had not thought that before.. thanks